# Boot Camp not working, unable to partition drive

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, ssd, big-sur

I would like to use Windows 10 in order to test the speed of selected apps in it. Unfortunately, I am not able to properly install it on macOS Big Sur, in a Late 2013 MacBook Pro.

Whenever I try to do Boot Camp, and I even deleted a lot of files in order to recover more free space, the message that I always received is about an error in partitioning my SSD drive.

What I did is to launch Disk Utility, either in the regular desktop or recovery mode, and I still encounter the same error messages, which are below:

```
Partitioning disk “APPLE SSD SM0512F Media” (disk0)

Resizing the startup volume will cause this computer to stop responding.

Running operation 1 of 2: Add “UNTITLED” 63.99 GB by shrinking container disk1 “Macintosh HD” (disk0s2) from 500.07 GB to 436.08 GB…
Aligning shrink delta to 63,990,759,424 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 436,077,277,184 bytes
Determined the minimum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 353,093,287,936 bytes
Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk1
The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk0s2
Verifying storage system
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l /dev/disk0s2
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Macintosh HD - Data was formatted by diskmanagementd (1677.50.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (1677.81.1).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fcad0 + 512) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fdd50 + 512) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fd3d0 + 256) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fcfd0 + 1024) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fd4d0 + 1024) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fe350 + 512) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fdbd0 + 384) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fced0 + 256) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fd8d0 + 768) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fe150 + 512) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fdf50 + 512) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x68fccd0 + 512) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fcad0 + 512)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fccd0 + 512)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fced0 + 256)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fcfd0 + 1024)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fd3d0 + 256)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fd4d0 + 1024)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fd8d0 + 768)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fdbd0 + 384)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fdd50 + 512)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fdf50 + 512)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fe150 + 512)
error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (0x68fe350 + 512)
warning: apfs_fs_alloc_count is not valid (expected 80497892, actual 80504804)
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Preboot was formatted by diskmanagementd (1677.50.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (1677.81.1).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Recovery was formatted by diskmanagementd (1677.50.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (1677.81.1).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume VM was formatted by diskmanagementd (1677.50.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (1677.81.1).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Macintosh HD was formatted by storagekitd (1677.50.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (1677.81.1).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking snapshot 1 of 1 (com.apple.os.update-CE63**censored***)
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the file extent tree.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Update was formatted by com.apple.Mobile (1677.50.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (1677.81.1).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Verifying allocated space.
warning: overallocation detected on Main device: (0x68fcad0+6784) bitmap address (0x7c97)
warning: overallocation detected on Main device: (0x6d37e00+128) bitmap address (0x97f3)
The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK.
Storage system check exit code is 0.
Shrinking APFS Physical Store disk0s2 from 500,068,036,608 to 436,077,277,184 bytes
Shrinking APFS data structures
APFS Container Resize error code is 49174
A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures. : (-69606)

Operation failed…
```

Moving forward, I was thinking that there might be an error with my SSD already? Or do I need to do a fresh installation of macOS Big Sur again in order to resolve it?

I hope you will all be helping me out with this.

Thanks so much!